# Convert date in format MM/DD/YYYY to MySQL date

Tags: php, mysql

I have a PHP function that gets passed a date in the format `MM/DD/YYYY`
I need to then convert this so that it can be added to a MySQL field that is of type `date`

How would I go about doing this in PHP?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: @Amal Murali Not yet no as I couldnt find anything on converting it, and am not sure what formats MySQL date will accept

Answer (score 29, accepted):

```
$newvalue = date('Y-m-d', strtotime($originalvalue));
```

Answer (score 7):

MySQL displays the DATE type as `'YYYY-MM-DD',` so you could do something like:

`date("Y-m-d",strtotime("10/18/2013"));`

Comment: thank you! it worked for me even with PHP7

Answer (score 4):

My variant:

> ```
>   $mysql_date = date('Y-m-d', strtotime(str_replace('/','-', $value)));
> ```

Comment: I think php `strtotime()` is smart enough to convert the string to time, even with the `/`, so you don't really have to do str_replace

Comment: @OniyaDaniel, what you are saying is not working with php 5.6, so I had to use this answer to see it working

Comment: Ok, that's great!

Answer (score 1):

```
$date = preg_replace('/(\d{2})\/(\d{2})\/(\d{4})/', '$3-$1-$2', $date)
```