# Date Format in mm-dd-yyyy

Tags: php

The below code displays date in yyyy-mm-dd

```
 <td>
<?php 
echo($data['Date']);?></td> 
  <td>
```

I want it in mm-dd-yyyy

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert date in format MM/DD/YYYY to MySQL date](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19459119/convert-date-in-format-mm-dd-yyyy-to-mysql-date)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Convert date format yyyy-mm-dd => dd-mm-yyyy](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2487921/convert-date-format-yyyy-mm-dd-dd-mm-yyyy)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

Use `strtotime($data['Date'])` to convert string to date time

and the use `date('m-d-Y',strtotime($data['Date']))` to format it to your requirement

```
<td>
<?php echo date('m-d-Y',strtotime($data['Date']));?>
</td>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$originalDate = "2010-03-21"; 
$newDate = date("m-d-Y", strtotime($originalDate));
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$s_date = $_POST['your_date_field'] // your date variable in  '2015-10-10 ' formate
echo date('m-d-Y',strtotime($s_date)) // return 10-10-2015
```

Comment: its displying like 01-01-1970

Comment: check your $)POST field if $_POST is null then it will display 01-01-1970 otherwise it will convert date ....